# Angular Array not updating after maping function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, higher-order-functions

I have an array of Categories that I filter when a user click on a button that selects a specific categories to view. however after maping the categories array, the categories display the desired result in the console however it seems to get lost somehow and the categories dont update in the DOM?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initCategories();
    this.shopService.filterCategories.subscribe(
      (fCategory: string) => {
        const filteredCategories = this.categories.filter(category => {
          return category.name !== fCategory;
        });
        for (const obj of filteredCategories) {
          obj.checked = false;
        }
        const newCategories = [];
        this.categories.map(obj => {
          filteredCategories.filter(fCat => obj);
          newCategories.push(obj);
        });
        this.categories = newCategories;
        console.log(this.categories)
      }
    );
  }
  initCategories(){
    this.categories = [
      {name: 'dress', checked: true, displayName: 'Dresses'},
      {name: 'top',   checked: true, displayName: 'Shirts'},
      {name: 'skirt', checked: true, displayName: 'Skirts/Pants'},
      {name: 'purse', checked: true, displayName: 'Purse'},
      {name: 'bag',   checked: true, displayName: 'Bags'},
    ];
  }
```

result

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "dress", checked: true, displayName: "Dresses"}
1: {name: "top", checked: false, displayName: "Shirts"}
2: {name: "skirt", checked: false, displayName: "Skirts/Pants"}
3: {name: "purse", checked: false, displayName: "Purse"}
4: {name: "bag", checked: false, displayName: "Bags"}
```

however when I log the categories array in ngAfterViewInit 
I get this.

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "dress", checked: true, displayName: "Dresses"}
1: {name: "top", checked: true, displayName: "Shirts"}
2: {name: "skirt", checked: true, displayName: "Skirts/Pants"}
3: {name: "purse", checked: true, displayName: "Purse"}
4: {name: "bag", checked: true, displayName: "Bags"}
```

what I tried

```
this.shopService.filterCategories.subscribe(
      (fCategory: string) => {
        const filteredCategories = this.categories.filter(category => {
          return category.name !== fCategory;
        });
        for (const obj of filteredCategories) {
          obj.checked = false;
        }
        let newCategories;
        newCategories = [...this.categories.map(obj => {
          filteredCategories.filter(fCat => obj);
        })];
        this.categories = newCategories;
        console.log(this.categories)
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: How are you displaying `this.categories` in your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to play with

```
        this.categories.map(obj => {
          filteredCategories.filter(fCat => obj);
```

both of them return a new array, they don't touch current one.
Therefore I would assume that `filteredCategories.filter` at least should be assigned somewhere.

```js
// an empty array
const newCategories = [];

// starting a loop, forEach would fit here better because it doesn't return anything.
this.categories.map(obj => {
  // the result of this filter won't be assigned anywhere.
  filteredCategories.filter(fCat => obj);

  // pushing obj to newCategories for every iteration.
  // may be you need to wrap it with `if` based on filter result.
  newCategories.push(obj);
});

// newCategories is an array with the same items as this.categories.
// because we simply iterate without any conditions.
console.log(newCategories);
```

---

In the update part of your question `filter` still doesn't do anything.
Its result should be assigned or used in a condition.

```js
        newCategories = [...this.categories.map(obj => {
          filteredCategories.filter(fCat => obj); // <- should be assigned
        })];
```

---

if you want to add only filtered only active category.

```js
    ngOnInit() {
        this.initCategories();
        this.shopService.filterCategories.subscribe(
            (fCategory: string) => {
                const filteredCategories: FilterBarComponent['categories'] = [];
                for (const category of this.categories) {
                    filteredCategories.push({
                        ...category,
                        checked: category.name === fCategory,
                    });
                }

                this.categories = filteredCategories;
                this.updateCategories();
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing that, and my categories still are unchanged.

Comment: do you want to check whether `obj` in `filteredCategories` and to add the `obj` to newCategories in this case?

Comment: I've added an example how to filter categories based on filteredCategories, shouldn't you simply use `filteredCategories`?

Comment: doing the last thing you mention returns
` [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: I've updated the code. now it filters categories by name and marks checked as false.

Comment: I still get undefined. this is strange as I have done this sort of thing before, I just cant understand why the `this.categories` is fine in ngOnit but in ngAfterViewInit it goes back to what it was

Comment: perhaps `initCategories()` is called somewhere else except `ngOnInit`. About undefined - try to add `console.log(this.categories);` before `const filteredCategories = [];` to ensure `this.categories` has data you need.

Comment: I also thought about that, but initCategories is only used once.What is also strange is that if I make newCategories a global variable it get cleared in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213416/discussion-between-satantime-and-mitch).